# Ιncompatible versions , trying to build my apk

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

Im tyring to make the apk from my app but it hit this problem :

```
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.Find the latest version on                     https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update C:\Users\xxx\android\build.gradle: ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

But when i updade it in for example 1.9.0 like this :

Build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

it says this :

```
module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
```

I cant understand i must update or not the kotlin version?
Also my app build grandle is this :
App/Build.Gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 28//flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 31//28//flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}
```

What is happening im like trying for 3 hours now ...

Comment: When you change Kotlin Version you need to make some changes in ```build.gradle(app-level)``` to run project. Meanwhile you can try with Kotlin Version ```1.8.20``` or ```1.9.20```.

Comment: I tried all that versions , what do you mean by some changes in app leve? Thanks..

Comment: please share your build.gradle file so I can look into the problem

Comment: Sure : ```buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}```  Do you need the rest file ? Because its too big to post it here .

Comment: Don't paste it here Edit the question and add there ```build.gradle``` of App Module

Comment: Sorry my bad im fool ,i edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Use kotlin version is

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

Comment: It says me this : ```[!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin. │  
│ Find the latest version on                                             │  
│ https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │  
│ C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\Mobile                                 │  
│ Dev\flutter\app\android\build.gradle:                                 │  
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>' ```